# Java thread pool to automatically enqueue and execute/submit a new thread, when one dies

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool

I have a thread pool created with `ExecutorService.newFixedThreadPool`. I have `executed` exactly the same number of threads into this pool, and my threads are forever running daemon. I want exactly n theads of the same logic running. Sure, I can supply "enough" threads into the queue of this thread pool, but I can't put infinite number into it. One way that might "cover enough ground", is in my thread, I can `catch (Throwable e)` and after that, start over as if the thread is new. But this seems hacky. Any suggestion?

Thanks

I searched the internet and StackOverflow especially. But most literature assumes the threads are meant to finish, which doesn't apply here.

Comment: The run() method of a Runnable is a thread entry point. It is always a good practice to wrap the code in a thread entry point with a try/catch. This will prevent the thread from exiting due to an exception, in in most cases keep the thread alive. There is nothing "hacky" about this.

Answer (score 0):

**ThreadPoolExecutor** has already implemented it, add a new worker when one die automatically.

In **Worker.runWorker()** - Main worker run loop

```
Thread wt = Thread.currentThread();
Runnable task = w.firstTask;
w.firstTask = null;
w.unlock(); // allow interrupts
boolean completedAbruptly = true;

try {
   while (task != null || (task = getTask()) != null) {
       ...
       try {
            beforeExecute(wt, task);
            Throwable thrown = null;
            try {
               task.run();
            } catch (RuntimeException x) {
                thrown = x; throw x;
            } catch (Error x) {
                thrown = x; throw x;
            } catch (Throwable x) {
                thrown = x; throw new Error(x);
            } finally {
                afterExecute(task, thrown);
            }
        } finally {
            task = null;
            w.completedTasks++;
            w.unlock();
        }
    }
    completedAbruptly = false;
} finally {
    processWorkerExit(w, completedAbruptly);
}
```

In **processWorkerExit()**: Performs cleanup and bookkeeping for a dying worker

```
if (completedAbruptly) // If abrupt, then workerCount wasn't adjusted
    decrementWorkerCount();

final ReentrantLock mainLock = this.mainLock;
mainLock.lock();
try {
    completedTaskCount += w.completedTasks;
    workers.remove(w);
} finally {
    mainLock.unlock();
}

tryTerminate();

...

if (runStateLessThan(c, STOP)) {
    ...
    addWorker(null, false);
}
```